# NPE in Hiibernate Web App

Tags: java, hibernate

I am developing a Hibernate project which requires a teacher to sign up by a form.

Teacheradd.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.time.LocalDateTime"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Calendar"%>
<%@include file="header.jsp"%>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
        <form class="border" action="addTeacher" method="post" style="">
            <center><h2 style="color: whitesmoke">Sign Up</h2><hr style="margin:0px" /></center>
            <div style="z-index: 100; background: whitesmoke">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="">Enter Name</label><req>*</req>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" required="true" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name"/>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="">Enter Father`s Name</label><req>*</req>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" required="true" name="fname" placeholder="Enter Father`s Name"/>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="">Enter DOB</label><req>*</req>
                    <input class="form-control" type="date" required="true" name="dob" max="<%out.print((LocalDateTime.now().getYear()-18) + "-01-01");%>"/>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="">Enter Gender</label><req>*</req><br/>
                    <select name="gender" class="form-control">
                            <option value="0">Male</option>
                            <option value="1">Female</option>
                    </select>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="">Enter Phone Number</label><req>*</req>
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" required="true" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone"/>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="">Enter Email</label><req>*</req>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" required="true" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email"/>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="">Enter Address</label><req>*</req>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" required="true" name="address1" placeholder="Address Line 1"/>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address2" placeholder="Address Line 2"/>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" required="true" name="city" placeholder="City"/>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" required="true" name="pincode" placeholder="Pincode"/>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" required="true" name="state" placeholder="State"/>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <%@include file="countrylistselect.jsp" %>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="">Joining Date</label><req>*</req>
                    <input class="form-control" type="date" required="true" name="joindate" value="<%out.print(LocalDateTime.now().toLocalDate());%>" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="">Enter Password</label><req>*</req>
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" required="true" name="pass" placeholder="Password"/>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="">Confirm Password</label><req>*</req>
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" required="true" name="pass2" placeholder="Re-type Password"/>
            </div>
            <center>
                <input type="checkbox" name="accept-eula" id="eula"/> <label for="eula">By checking this box, I agree to <a href="#">all terms</a> to use Teacher<sup>TM</sup></label><br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-bottom: 10px"/>
            </center>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<%@include file="footer.jsp" %>
```

The values go to this servlet

addTeacher

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package com.newidea.tottracker.servlets;

import com.newidea.tottracker.action.TeacherAction;
import com.newidea.tottracker.mappings.Teacher;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
//import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author Mohit
 */
public class addTeacher extends HttpServlet {

    String name, fname, phno, email, address1, address2, city, state, country, pass1, pass2;
    int gender, pincode, tid;
    LocalDate dob, doj;

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet addTeacher</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet addTeacher at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
//        processRequest(request, response);
        initializeParams(request);
        showValues(response);
        if(pass1.equals(pass2)){
                 addNewTeacher();
                 response.getWriter().println("Teacher ID : " + tid);
                 response.getWriter().println("Added successfully");
            }
        else{
            response.getWriter().println("Passwords do not match! Try again");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>


    private void initializeParams(HttpServletRequest request) {
            name = request.getParameter("name");
            fname = request.getParameter("fname");
            dob = LocalDate.parse(request.getParameter("dob"));
            gender = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("gender"));
            phno = request.getParameter("phone");
            email = request.getParameter("email");
            address1 = request.getParameter("address1");
            address2 = request.getParameter("address2");
            city = request.getParameter("city");
            pincode = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pincode"));
            state = request.getParameter("state");
            country = request.getParameter("country");
            doj = LocalDate.parse(request.getParameter("joindate"));
            pass1 = request.getParameter("pass");
            pass2 = request.getParameter("pass2");
    }

    private void addNewTeacher() {
        Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
            teacher.setTeacherName(name);
            teacher.setTeacherFname(fname);
            teacher.setTeacherDob(dob);
            teacher.setTeacherGender(gender);
            teacher.setTeacherPhone(phno);
            teacher.setTeacherEmail(email);
            teacher.setAddress1(address1);
            teacher.setAddress2(address2);
            teacher.setCity(city);
            teacher.setPincode(pincode);
            teacher.setState(state);
            teacher.setCountry(country);
            teacher.setTeacherDoj(doj);
            teacher.setTeacherStatus("true");
            teacher.setTeacherLastLogin(LocalDateTime.now());
            TeacherAction action = new TeacherAction();
            tid = action.addTeacher(teacher);

    }

    private void showValues(HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(fname);
            System.out.println(dob);
            System.out.println(gender);
            System.out.println(phno);
            System.out.println(email);
            System.out.println(address1);
            System.out.println(address2);
            System.out.println(city);
            System.out.println(pincode);
            System.out.println(state);
            System.out.println(country);
            System.out.println(doj);
            System.out.println(pass1);
            System.out.println(pass2);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(addTeacher.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

and

Teacher.java

```
package com.newidea.tottracker.mappings;
// Generated 17 Feb, 2016 11:21:31 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.6.0


import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Teacher generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Teacher  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer teacherId;
     private String teacherName;
     private String teacherFname;
     private LocalDate teacherDob;
     private int teacherGender;
     private String teacherPhone;
     private String address1;
     private String address2;
     private String city;
     private int pincode;
     private String state;
     private String country;
     private String teacherEmail;
     private String teacherStatus;
     private LocalDate teacherDoj;
     private LocalDateTime teacherLastLogin;
     private String teacherLastLoginIp;
     private String teacherLevel;
     private Set classrooms = new HashSet(0);

    public Teacher() {
    }


    public Teacher(String teacherName, String teacherFname, LocalDate teacherDob, int teacherGender, String teacherPhone, String address1, String city, int pincode, String state, String country, String teacherEmail, String teacherStatus, LocalDate teacherDoj, LocalDateTime teacherLastLogin, String teacherLastLoginIp, String teacherLevel) {
        this.teacherName = teacherName;
        this.teacherFname = teacherFname;
        this.teacherDob = teacherDob;
        this.teacherGender = teacherGender;
        this.teacherPhone = teacherPhone;
        this.address1 = address1;
        this.city = city;
        this.pincode = pincode;
        this.state = state;
        this.country = country;
        this.teacherEmail = teacherEmail;
        this.teacherStatus = teacherStatus;
        this.teacherDoj = teacherDoj;
        this.teacherLastLogin = teacherLastLogin;
        this.teacherLastLoginIp = teacherLastLoginIp;
        this.teacherLevel = teacherLevel;
    }
    public Teacher(String teacherName, String teacherFname, LocalDate teacherDob, int teacherGender, String teacherPhone, String address1, String address2, String city, int pincode, String state, String country, String teacherEmail, String teacherStatus, LocalDate teacherDoj, LocalDateTime teacherLastLogin, String teacherLastLoginIp, String teacherLevel, Set classrooms) {
       this.teacherName = teacherName;
       this.teacherFname = teacherFname;
       this.teacherDob = teacherDob;
       this.teacherGender = teacherGender;
       this.teacherPhone = teacherPhone;
       this.address1 = address1;
       this.address2 = address2;
       this.city = city;
       this.pincode = pincode;
       this.state = state;
       this.country = country;
       this.teacherEmail = teacherEmail;
       this.teacherStatus = teacherStatus;
       this.teacherDoj = teacherDoj;
       this.teacherLastLogin = teacherLastLogin;
       this.teacherLastLoginIp = teacherLastLoginIp;
       this.teacherLevel = teacherLevel;
       this.classrooms = classrooms;
    }

    public Integer getTeacherId() {
        return this.teacherId;
    }

    public void setTeacherId(Integer teacherId) {
        this.teacherId = teacherId;
    }
    public String getTeacherName() {
        return this.teacherName;
    }

    public void setTeacherName(String teacherName) {
        this.teacherName = teacherName;
    }
    public String getTeacherFname() {
        return this.teacherFname;
    }

    public void setTeacherFname(String teacherFname) {
        this.teacherFname = teacherFname;
    }
    public LocalDate getTeacherDob() {
        return this.teacherDob;
    }

    public void setTeacherDob(LocalDate teacherDob) {
        this.teacherDob = teacherDob;
    }
    public int getTeacherGender() {
        return this.teacherGender;
    }

    public void setTeacherGender(int teacherGender) {
        this.teacherGender = teacherGender;
    }
    public String getTeacherPhone() {
        return this.teacherPhone;
    }

    public void setTeacherPhone(String teacherPhone) {
        this.teacherPhone = teacherPhone;
    }
    public String getAddress1() {
        return this.address1;
    }

    public void setAddress1(String address1) {
        this.address1 = address1;
    }
    public String getAddress2() {
        return this.address2;
    }

    public void setAddress2(String address2) {
        this.address2 = address2;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public int getPincode() {
        return this.pincode;
    }

    public void setPincode(int pincode) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return this.state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getTeacherEmail() {
        return this.teacherEmail;
    }

    public void setTeacherEmail(String teacherEmail) {
        this.teacherEmail = teacherEmail;
    }
    public String getTeacherStatus() {
        return this.teacherStatus;
    }

    public void setTeacherStatus(String teacherStatus) {
        this.teacherStatus = teacherStatus;
    }
    public LocalDate getTeacherDoj() {
        return this.teacherDoj;
    }

    public void setTeacherDoj(LocalDate teacherDoj) {
        this.teacherDoj = teacherDoj;
    }
    public LocalDateTime getTeacherLastLogin() {
        return this.teacherLastLogin;
    }

    public void setTeacherLastLogin(LocalDateTime teacherLastLogin) {
        this.teacherLastLogin = teacherLastLogin;
    }
    public String getTeacherLastLoginIp() {
        return this.teacherLastLoginIp;
    }

    public void setTeacherLastLoginIp(String teacherLastLoginIp) {
        this.teacherLastLoginIp = teacherLastLoginIp;
    }
    public String getTeacherLevel() {
        return this.teacherLevel;
    }

    public void setTeacherLevel(String teacherLevel) {
        this.teacherLevel = teacherLevel;
    }
    public Set getClassrooms() {
        return this.classrooms;
    }

    public void setClassrooms(Set classrooms) {
        this.classrooms = classrooms;
    }




}
```

TeacherAction.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.newidea.tottracker.action;

import com.newidea.tottracker.mappings.Teacher;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

/**
 *
 * @author Mohit
 */
public class TeacherAction extends BaseAction {

    Session session;
    Transaction tx = null;
    Integer tid = null;

    public TeacherAction() {
        super();
    }

    public Integer addTeacher(Teacher teacher) {
        session = getSessionFactory().openSession();

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            tid = (Integer) session.save(teacher);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return tid;
    }

    public void deleteTeacher(Integer tid) {

        session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Teacher teacher = (Teacher) session.get(Teacher.class, tid);
            session.delete(teacher);
            tx.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
            if(tx != null) tx.rollback();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally{
            session.close();
        }

    }

    public void updateTeacher(Integer tid, Teacher newTeacher){

        session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Teacher oldTeacher = (Teacher) session.get(Teacher.class, tid);
            oldTeacher.setTeacherName(newTeacher.getTeacherName());
            oldTeacher.setTeacherFname(newTeacher.getTeacherFname());
            oldTeacher.setTeacherDob(newTeacher.getTeacherDob());
            oldTeacher.setTeacherGender(newTeacher.getTeacherGender());
            oldTeacher.setTeacherPhone(newTeacher.getTeacherPhone());
            oldTeacher.setAddress1(newTeacher.getAddress1());
            oldTeacher.setAddress2(newTeacher.getAddress2());
            oldTeacher.setCity(newTeacher.getCity());
            oldTeacher.setPincode(newTeacher.getPincode());
            oldTeacher.setState(newTeacher.getState());
            oldTeacher.setCountry(newTeacher.getCountry());
            oldTeacher.setTeacherEmail(newTeacher.getTeacherEmail());
            oldTeacher.setTeacherStatus(newTeacher.getTeacherStatus());
            oldTeacher.setTeacherDoj(newTeacher.getTeacherDoj());
            oldTeacher.setTeacherLastLoginIp(newTeacher.getTeacherLastLoginIp());
//            oldTeacher.setTeacherLevel(newTeacher.getTeacherLevel());
            session.merge(oldTeacher);
            tx.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
            if(tx != null) tx.rollback();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally{
            session.close();
        }

    }

}
```

The following is the stacktrace:

```
18-Feb-2016 17:04:54.313 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-83] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [addTeacher] in context with path [/Hibernate] threw exception
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.newidea.tottracker.servlets.addTeacher.addNewTeacher(addTeacher.java:146)
    at com.newidea.tottracker.servlets.addTeacher.doPost(addTeacher.java:89)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And server logs:

```
18-Feb-2016 17:04:53.049 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-83] org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/newidea/tottracker/mappings/ExamType.hbm.xml
18-Feb-2016 17:04:53.057 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-83] org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/newidea/tottracker/mappings/Role.hbm.xml
18-Feb-2016 17:04:53.125 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-83] org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/newidea/tottracker/mappings/Teacher.hbm.xml
18-Feb-2016 17:04:53.141 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-83] org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/newidea/tottracker/mappings/Course.hbm.xml
18-Feb-2016 17:04:53.149 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-83] org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
18-Feb-2016 17:04:53.269 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-83] org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
18-Feb-2016 17:04:53.277 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-83] org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
18-Feb-2016 17:04:53.277 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-83] org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
18-Feb-2016 17:04:53.277 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-83] org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sms?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull]
18-Feb-2016 17:04:53.277 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-83] org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root}
18-Feb-2016 17:04:53.625 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-83] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
18-Feb-2016 17:04:53.801 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-83] org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator.initiateService HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
18-Feb-2016 17:04:53.809 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-83] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.<init> HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Exception : java.time.LocalDate cannot be cast to java.util.Date
```

Can anyone help as it is driving me crazy!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: which line gives you the error?

Comment: action.addTeacher(teacher); in the servlet

Comment: I updated the answer. If you're still getting a NullPointerException check the server logs for what the next error is when it fails to save the entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appear to be two different errors and one might be misleading, caused somehow by the other. As you can see in the server logs:

```
Exception : java.time.LocalDate cannot be cast to java.util.Date
```

There is no direct conversion to the legacy date type. There is a workaround, but if you're just going to use the old date type, you might as well change the following line:

```
        teacher.setTeacherLastLogin(LocalDateTime.now());
```

to:

```
        teacher.setTeacherLastLogin(new java.util.Date());
```

If you insist on using the new date API, you can add the `hibernate-java8` package to your dependencies to support them directly. However the `Instant` type is more appropriate for a timestamp, than a LocalDateTime.

edit1:
The NullPointerException is caused by the `action.addTeacher(teacher)` function returning `null` and trying to convert it to a primitive value. I believe that the date problem is what causes the exception in the server logs (the last list of logs, anyway), so the `TeacherAction.tid` is still `null` when the function returns.

Comment: I have added that conversion to the LocalDate to Date. That doesnt seem to make any error. The lne action.addTeacher(teacher); causes the real pain.